# How to stop processes from running during data import for Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are currently using SSIS packages and Kingswaysoft to update our Dynamics365 CRM environment with data from our old system. During this import process we have to disable active processes and turn them back on once the import process is complete. This is very error prone as sometimes people will forget to turn the processes back on and we simple have far too many processes as well.

For example, if I import 1.2 million records, I wouldn't want 1.2 million workflows to run as well and scenarios like that have brought the CRM environment to its knees and/or ballooned the LogBase tables to the point that we had to get MS to clear them.

What is the best practice here? Should we programmatically get a list of all active processes, disable them, and store that list somewhere and then once the import process is done, we enable those processes again? If we do need to do it programmatically, then how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

#### The easy way

You could add all the workflows that you need to disable to a solution. That solution would function just as "grouping" mechanism for the workflows. That way when you need to run the import you know that you need to disable all the workflows referenced in the solution.

#### The hard (fun) way

If you want to invest more time into pragmatically disabling the workflows you could create a console application that calls the Dynamics 365 API and updates the workflow status.

**Request**

```
PATCH [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/workflows(00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000)
HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0

{
    "statecode": 0, // Draft = 0 | Activated = 1
    "statuscode": 0, // Draft = 0 | Activated = 1
}
```

For details about updating a record using the Web API see [Update and delete entities using the Web API: Basic Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/update-delete-entities-using-web-api?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#basic-update)
For workflow statecode and statuscode option set values see [workflow EntityType: Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/workflow?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#properties)